# How to play one frame animation in WPF?

Tags: c#, wpf, animation

I get this project code [WPF Animation](https://www.codeproject.com/Articles/364529/Animation-using-Storyboards-in-WPF) and I'm trying to run one frame animation when I click on an additional button

```
public partial class MainWindow : Window
{
    int ctr = 1;
    public MainWindow()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
    }

    private void DoubleAnimation_Completed(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        ShowImage();
        da.BeginAnimation(Image.WidthProperty, da);
    }

    private void ShowImage()
    {
        string filename = "Images/Flag" + ctr + ".jpg";
        BitmapImage image = new BitmapImage();
        image.BeginInit();
        image.UriSource = new Uri(filename, UriKind.Relative);
        image.EndInit();
        flagImage.Source = image;
        ctr++;
        if (ctr > 6)
        {
            ctr = 1;
        }
    }

    private void button_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {   
        // --> BreakPoint here  <--
        DoubleAnimation_Completed(sender, e);
        DoubleAnimation_Completed(null, null);
    }
}
```

XAML

```xml
<Window x:Class="AnimatedFlag.MainWindow"
        xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
        xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
        Title="Indian Flag" Height="534.351" Width="525">
    <Grid Margin="0,0,0,-102">
        <Image Name="flagImage" Margin="12,12,12,263">
            <Image.Triggers>
                <EventTrigger RoutedEvent="Window.Loaded">
                    <BeginStoryboard>
                        <Storyboard>
                            <DoubleAnimation Name="da" Storyboard.TargetName="flagImage" Storyboard.TargetProperty="Width" From="200" To="200" Duration="0:0:0.1" Completed="DoubleAnimation_Completed"/>
                        </Storyboard>
                    </BeginStoryboard>
                </EventTrigger>
            </Image.Triggers>
        </Image>
        <Button x:Name="button" Content="Button" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="153,364,0,0" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="75" Click="button_Click"/>
    </Grid>
</Window>
```

Problem :
When I put a breakPoint on `button_Click` and try to run one frame animation it not work. Why it work outside `button_Click` and not in my `button_Click` ? The idea is : If I can make it work in my button, I will try to do same thing from an External Thread to solve a big problem that I have now

Comment: What do you mean with "one frame animation"? What do you want your button to do? What is the "big problem" you have"? Why would you call `DoubleAnimation_Completed` yourself?

Comment: @CorentinPane one frame animation is to show the NEXT picture to simulate animation (see what `ShowImage` do in code above). my big problem was described here [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69590453/how-can-we-interrupt-the-ui-thread). I need to play lot of GIF animations on main View when UI Thread do small processing (less than 200ms) WITHOUT any freeze of GIF. If I can reduce freeze by using jpeg, I will modify our application code to avoid using GIF.